# Cannot convert value of type 'Object.Type' to expected argument type 'Object'

Tags: swift, class

I am a newbie to Swift so I apologize if this is dumb question.  I am trying to allocate an object and pass it the parent's self.

What I have is like:

```
  class Maze { 
      var rat : MazeRat 

      init () {
        
        rat = MazeRat(self: Maze)
    }

  }

and

class MazeRat{
     init( maze : Maze ) {
        
    }
}
```

But XCode objects to "self" in the call, insisting it should be 'maze'.  But if that change is made I get the error:

```
  Cannot convert value of type 'Maze.Type' to expected argument type 'Maze'
```

TIA for any help.

Comment: There is no parent here so I am curious what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, sorry if I wasn't clear, I think of the Maze as the parent and the Rat as the child since it is a member of Maze.

Comment: Does the rat have to have a reference to the maze, isn’t it enough with a one directional reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the current instance of `Maze` as `self`.

Notice in each example the use of the `unowned` or `weak` keywords here, to prevent a strong reference between `Maze` and `MazeRat`.

However, since `self` isn't available yet as `rat` hasn't been initialized - you need to give `rat` an initial value first.

Example:

```
class Maze {
    private(set) var rat: MazeRat!

    init() {
        rat = nil
        rat = MazeRat(maze: self)
    }
}

class MazeRat {
    unowned let maze: Maze

    init(maze: Maze) {
        self.maze = maze
    }
}
```

---

Another method is to initialize `MazeRat`, then set the `maze` instance, like so:

```
class Maze {
    let rat: MazeRat

    init() {
        rat = MazeRat()
        rat.maze = self
    }
}

class MazeRat {
    weak var maze: Maze?

    init() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, George.  That's the explanation I needed.

Comment: Small followup.  Since the Maze member in MazeRat is now an optional, all refs to Maze have to be unwrapped, i.e. maze!.nRow etc.  Is it acceptable, good practice or frowned on to do something like  let uwMask = mask!   Just to avoid bangs everywhere.

Comment: @rkwright I have edited the first example to make use of `unowned`. Now, in `MazeRat`, you can refer to `maze` without optionals. You shouldn't be force unwrapping `weak` variables, since they may be `nil` at the time you read from them.

Comment: @rkwright The difference between `weak` and `unowned` (even for me) is still one of the hardest things to understand. There is a good quote [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1438800464767_118798), and paragraph underneath explaining why `unowned` may be better for your situation. `"If you know your reference is going to be zeroed out properly and your 2 references are MUTUALLY DEPENDENT on each other (one can't live without the other), then you should prefer unowned over weak"`.

Comment: @rkwright Basically `weak` should be used here if you can have a `MazeRat` instance that no longer belongs to a `Maze`, which I doubt would be your case.